# jQuery sifr plugin (thewikies.com) and IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, sifr

Is someone able to use jQuery sifr plugin, from thewikies.com, with Internet Explorer ?

I reduce code to minimum :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/DTD/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.1-3-1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.sifr.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.sifr({ build: 436, version: 3, path: '.' , save: true});
    $('.try').sifr({font: 'myown'});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="try">Blabla blabla </h1>
  <p class="try">Yonga Lorem ipsum...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

It's work on FF... but the h1 ! And on IE, we see the replacment but original text is not hidden, despite opacity to 0 (added by plugin).

Do you know a better implementation of sIFR for jQuery ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. This plugin doesn't work with IE and author never answer to email.
Very simple to found, but as often, it was longer to find...

I replaced :

```
(($.browser.msie) ? 'zoom:1;filter:alpha(opacity=0)': 'opacity:0')
```

by :

```
(($.support.opacity) ? 'opacity:0' : 'zoom:1;visibility:hidden')
```

$.support.opacity just because jQuery team recommend to use this instead of $.browser.
And visibility because it works :)

But still impossible to make a fade on sIFRed text.